# Rheem Hybrid Water Heater Dead

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

My one-year old Rheem Hybrid Hot Water Heater (xe50t10hd50u0) is completely dead. Power to the unit is good (full 240v). Screen on the unit is blank. I've pressed the reset button; no help. Unfortunately, Rheem is closed because it is Sunday, so tech support is not available. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Is the plug four wire: hot1-hot2-neutral-gnd ?

Comment: It’s hard wired. Hot1-hot2-gnd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the motherboard was fried in the unit. Rheem sent a replacement unit (turns out it's the whole screen thing), and problem fixed. I did have to get a Rheem plumber to look at it. Part was free and overnighted to us; I did have to pay for labor, though.

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect the power to the unit and let it sit for 5 min and then repower it. You can either switch off the breaker or pull the plug.

Comment: I cut the breaker and left it off over 10 minutes; no improvement